# Re-size image using laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I installed a package intervention/image and tried   to  re-size image and save it in another directory but i have error
[image: Image for reference]
 `$img = Image::make('public/ddd.jpg')->resize(320, 240)->insert('public/watermark.png');`

Comment: instead of Image::make('public/ddd.jpg') try giving the absolute path to the image Image::make('c:/users/anema/../.../public/ddd.jpg')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$img = Image::make(public_path('ddd.jpg'))->resize(320, 240)->insert(public_path('watermark.jpg'));
```

Assuming the files `ddd.jpg` and `watermark.jpg` are in your `public` folder. `public_path()` is a helper function built in Laravel. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-public-path.